# Prove continuous maps $f,g: S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ are homotopic if $f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$ for all $x\in S^n$.

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, continuity, homotopy-theory

> Let $f: S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ and $g: S^{n} \rightarrow S^{n}$ be two continuous map on $S^{n}$. Suppose that, for all $x \in S^{n}$, we have $$f(x)\cdot g(x)=0\,.$$  Then show that $f \simeq g$.

For the definition of two homotopic functions, see [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy#:%7E:text=In%20topology%2C%20two%20continuous%20functions,homotopy%20between%20the%20two%20functions.).

For information, the operator $\cdot$ is the usual dot product in $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Also $S^n\subseteq\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$ is the unit sphere with center at the origin.

For $n=1$, the claim is not difficult to prove.  If $f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$, then $f(x)\perp g(x)$.  Treating $\mathbb{R}^2$ as $\mathbb{C}$.  Therefore, $f(x)=e^{\pm i\pi/2} g(x)$.  Because $f$ and $g$ are continuous, we must have $$f(x)=e^{si\pi/2}g(x)$$ for all $x\in S^1$, where $s=\pm 1$ is fixed.  In this case, we have a homotopy:
$$H(x,t)=e^{si\pi t/2}g(x)$$
where $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in S^1$.  Clearly, $H(x,0)=g(x)$ and $H(x,1)=f(x)$ for all $x\in S^1$.

How do we prove the statement for a general $n$?  Thanks in advance for sharing your knowledge.

Comment: How can $g(x)$ equal zero?

Comment: well consider it as a point in $S^{n}$. @AnginaSeng

Comment: I voted to close your question because there are missing important details. (1) $g(x) = 0$ does not make sense, perhaps you mean that $g$ is constant? (2) You cannot expect that a map $f$ about which you do not know anything is homotopic to a special $g$.

Comment: Does $S^n$ stand for the $n$-dimensional sphere? And are you assuming that $g$ is constant and $f$ arbitrary? Then this is false. It is well known that $S^n$ is not contractible.

Comment: sorry you are right, I miswrote the assumption! I edited it @AnginaSeng

Comment: I've made changes. please vote back! :) @PaulFrost

Comment: for example in some x g(x) = (1,0,0,..,0) and f(x)= (0,0,...,1) @freakish

Comment: I edited your question. Please use tex in the correct way for you questions (and comments)

Comment: And what do you mean by $f(x)\cdot g(x)$? Pointwise multiplication? Inner product?

Comment: I retracted my vote.

Comment: @Gabrielek sure thank you

Comment: @freakish inner product

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Presumably, the operator $\cdot$ is the standard inner product on $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$, and $$S^n:=\big\{x\in\mathbb{R}^{n+1}\,\big|\,\|x\|=1\big\}\,,$$
where $\|\_\|$ is the norm induced by the inner product $\cdot$.  Let $$h(t,x):=(1-t)\,f(x)+t\,g(x)\,,$$ where $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in S^n$.  Because $f(x)\cdot g(x)=0$ for all $x\in S^n$, we conclude that $h$ is a nonvanishing continuous map from $[0,1]\times S^n$ to $\mathbb{R}^{n+1}$.  Define $$H(t,x):=\frac{h(t,x)}{\big\|h(t,x)\big\|}$$
for all $t\in[0,1]$ and $x\in S^n$.  Then, $H:[0,1]\times S^n\to S^n$ is a continuous map such that $H(0,\_)=f$ and $H(1,\_)=g$.  Consequently, $H$ is a homotopy from $f$ to $g$.

**Remark.**  It suffices to know that $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ are linearly independent for every $x\in S^n$.  If this assumption is met, then $h(t,x)\neq 0$ for any $x\in S^n$ and $t\in[0,1]$.  Therefore, the same argument works.

Comment: Just as a reference if someone is confused on this point: if ever $h(t,x) = 0$ for any $t>0$, then $h(t,x)\cdot v = 0$ for all $v$; but as $f\cdot g = 0$ and $g\cdot g = 1$, we have $h(t,x)\cdot g(x) = t \neq 0$.